# Trackbar Gesture for Mission Control / Spaces: Two fingers + click

Tags: macos, mission-control, multi-touch

Up until Snow Leopard I was using a simple shortcut to navigate through Spaces (Desktops). Two fingers plus click would present Spaces and allow me to select desktop and/or window effortlessly. So my question is, how can I do that and start Mission Control instead?

Thank you for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On a trackpad:
slide with 4 fingers up to open Mission Control
slide with 4 fingers to the left or right to switch to another 'space'

On a magic mouse:
you can dubble tap with 2 fingers ( don't click ) on your mouse to open mission control

But assuming you have a mighty mouse ( your nickname ) you can assign Mission Control to a hot corner. Go to `System preferences` -> `Mission Control` -> and press the `hot corners` button to change or assign the hot corner you want.

Also you might want to check out [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de) which let you define al sorts of gestures on your magic mouse, normal mouse, touchpad and or keyboard. Assigning them to whatever you want. ( like opening Mission Control )

[image]